# scrollHeight doesn't work since last Chrome update

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I had this function for a long time and it made my iframe change height on click, but since the last update of chrome it stoped working on chrome. i get the value 0, while on explorer or other platform it works great. any ideas how to make it works again?

```
function calcHeight() {
        var the_height = document.getElementById('resize').contentWindow.document.body.scrollHeight;
        window.alert(the_height);
        document.getElementById('resize').height= the_height;
}
```

Comment: Does `*.document.documentElement.scrollHeight` work in your code?

Comment: Yes it is! thanks. don't know how I missed this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to change how you reference the document to:

```
var the_height =
  document.getElementById('resize').contentWindow.document.documentElement.scrollHeight;
```